# How to include the border of an area when checking area.contains(double x, double y)

Tags: java, border, contains, area, rectangles

I created areas that I now see are 1 too small in every direction because I didn't realize that area.contains(double x, double y) does not return true if the coordinates are on the border.  Without going back and changing hundreds of variables, is there a workaround or another method that will include the border?

Options:

- contains method that includes the border
- getting the border of the area as an array of points
- increasing the current areas by 1 in every direction
- other? suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Lee

Comment: Option 3 is probably the only viable choice. You could write a method that takes two areas, increases on by 1 pixel all the way around and does the compare for you...

Comment: I ended up just expanding the current areas. :/